# @RequestParam javax validation junit REST controller testing

Tags: rest, mockito, junit4

Is there a way to do spring controller unit testing for javax validations on @RequestParams.

I have a get method in controller which validates the size of the request param with @Size.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResultgetData(

            @Size(min=2, max=3)
             @RequestParam String number)
```

Is there a way to mock junit test the size validator? I would like to validate a error returned when the size  is <2 or > 3.

Sample test :

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private MyController myControllerMock;


@Before
public void initTest() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerInsuranceControllerMock).setControllerAdvice(exceptionHandler).build();
}

@Test
public void getEmptyData() throws Exception{



    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(
        "/getData?number={number}"
        , "")
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());  // This is failing. It returns a success as javax @Size is not triggered.When a empty string is passed , it should be bad request
```

}

I tried spring runner too ,but still seems to fail.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how are you testing the controller?

Comment: thanks cassiomolin..updated the request

Comment: Please let me know if my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739036/1426227) works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you could use [`@RunWith`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) with [`SpringRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html) and [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) with your controller and your exception handler classes.

As your question doesn't show what your controller looks like, let's consider the following controller that returns a greeting for the given name:

```java
@Data
public class Greeting {
    private String content;
}
```

```java
@Validated
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/greeting", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Greeting> getGreeting(
                @RequestParam @Size(min = 2, max = 10) String name) {

        Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
        greeting.setContent("Hello " + name + "!");

        return ResponseEntity.ok(greeting);
    }
}
```

Now let's consider an exception handler for [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html), which will be thrown when some validation fails:

```java
@Data
public class ApiError {
    private String message;
    private HttpStatus status;
    private Object details;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class InvalidValue {
    private String name;
    private Object value;
    private String message;
}
```

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class WebApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex,
                                                            WebRequest request) {

        List<InvalidValue> invalidValues = ex.getConstraintViolations()
                .stream()
                .map(this::toInvalidValue)
                .collect(toList());

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError();
        apiError.setMessage("Validation error");
        apiError.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        apiError.setDetails(invalidValues);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }

    private InvalidValue toInvalidValue(ConstraintViolation violation) {
        InvalidValue invalidValue = new InvalidValue();
        invalidValue.setName(violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
        invalidValue.setValue(violation.getInvalidValue());
        invalidValue.setMessage(violation.getMessage());
        return invalidValue;
    }
}
```

With this, you could write the tests and expectations as shown below:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest({GreetingController.class, WebApiExceptionHandler.class})
public class GreetingControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void getGreeting_shouldReturn200_whenNameIsValid() {

        mockMvc.perform(
                get("/greeting")
                        .param("name", "foo")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content").value("Hello foo!"));
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void getGreeting_shouldReturn400_whenNameIsInvalid() {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting").param("name", "_"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.*", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value("Validation error"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("BAD_REQUEST"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.details", hasSize(1)))

                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.details[0].*", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.details[0].name", is("getGreeting.name")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.details[0].value", is("_")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.details[0].message", is("size must be between 2 and 10")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cassiomolin, I have tried using it Spring Runner, but still my request return success status when my request param is of length < 2 . I am having increasing doubts now, if javax validations are possible at all in the controller

Comment: @stackuser As you haven't posted the controller class code, let me ask: Have you annotated your controller class with `@Validated`?

Comment: @stackuser If my answer solved your issue, please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted.

Comment: @cassiomolin Do you have a sample test that exploits validation using springboot 2.2.0.RELEASE. I have a test class which tests a controller query parameter validation and I am using `@SpringBootTest`, but validation never happens. Instead it gives me 200 response for empty value. Do you have any idea on why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems, 
1. You need to use `@Length` to validate the length of a String, `@Size` is to validate the number of items in a collection such as a `List`. If you are saying it must be an int of 2 or 3 then you need `@Min(2) @Max(3)`.
2. Your controller must be annotated with `@Validated`.