# JUnit Test wrongly pass with wrong parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I try to test a controller's method and get the proper exception. It fails only for the ConstraintViolationException (javax.validation), while to others such as MissingServletRequestParameterException or MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException tests are working as expected.

Down below there is a part of my code, where in the controller (@Validated), in the method i am adding these annotations.
There is also the ControllerAdvice and the test.
Postman, when i put wrong parameters returns the proper response:
{"value":500,"name":"ConstraintViolationException","message":"The param1 is wrong"}, but for some strange reason, JUnit asks for 200 instead of 500.

Controller

```
    @ResponseBody
    public Board method(@Min(value = 0) @Max(value = 5)  @RequestParam(value = "param1", required = true) int param1,
                     @Min(value = 0) @Max(value = 1)  @RequestParam(value = "param2", required = true) int param3){
        return service.meth(param1, param2);
    }
```

ControllerAdvice

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ErrorResponse handleInternalServerErrors(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        String message = "";
        if(ex instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            Map<String, Collection<String>> errors = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            final String[] queryParam = {""};
            ((ConstraintViolationException) ex).getConstraintViolations().forEach(constraintViolation -> {
                String queryParamPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
                queryParam[0] = queryParamPath.contains(".") ?
                        queryParamPath.substring(queryParamPath.indexOf(".") + 1) :
                        queryParamPath;
            });
            message = "The " + queryParam[0] + " is wrong";
        }

        return new ErrorResponse(
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
                ex.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                message);
    }
```

Test

```
 @Test
    void TryToGetException() throws Exception {
        given(service.meth(1231,1231)).willReturn(new CustObj());
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(get("/endpoint")
                .param("param1", "1231")
                .param("param2", "1231")

        ).andReturn().getResponse();

        assertEquals(response.getStatus(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    }
```

Expected :200
Actual   :500

What should i change in order to get the exception in the Test?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `return service.meth(param1, param2);` does the test hit it?

Comment: Hi, yes. Seems that it does not take into account the @min/@max.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56739036/2201165) relate to your problem? (take a look at the `@WebMvcTest` annotation)

Comment: Hi, did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private MockMvc mvcContext;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    mvcContext = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .build();
}
```

By using the `webAppContextSetup`, the problem solved.
It takes into account the @Min, @Max (in my case, genarally, the @Valid annotations)
and so i can have the exception for testing it!

```
@Test
void testConstraintViolationException() throws Exception {
   MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcContext.perform(get("/endpoint")
            .param("param1", "1231")
            .param("param2", "1231")
    assertEquals(response.getStatus(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
}
```